# How to print numbers in tkinter on a new page

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have created a program and I click the first radio button and click the button that says get total cost and when the window opens it doesn't give me the right value back.

```
import tkinter as tk
#make a new window
window10 = tk.Tk()
#lable what the page is
amgpage = tk.Label(window10, text="Mercedes Benz AMG Maintenance Calculator")
amgpage.pack(anchor='n')

#ask the user how many tires are needed
amgpage = tk.Label(window10, text="How many new tires do you need?")
amgpage.pack(anchor='w')

gr1=tk.IntVar()

def amgtires():
    x=227.92
    tiresa=(gr1.get())

    if (tiresa == 1):
        c=x
    elif(tiresa == 2):
        c=x+x
    elif(tiresa == 3):
        b=x+x+x
    elif(tiresa == 4):
        d=x+x+x+x
    elif(tiresa == 5):
        e=0
    return tiresa

def amgtotal():
#open a new page
    window17 = tk.Tk()
    a = amgtires()

    #total cost for tires
    amgpage = tk.Label(window17, text="Tire Cost: $"+ str(a))
    amgpage.pack(anchor='w')

    #size for window
    window17.geometry("400x400")

    #window title   
    window17.title("Mercedes Benz AMG Maintenance Total")

    #end of window 17   
    window17.mainloop()


#radio button on how many tire are needed
tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text="1",value=1,variable=gr1,command=amgtires).pack(anchor='w' )
tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text="2",value=2,variable=gr1,command=amgtires).pack(anchor='w' )
tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text="3",value=3,variable=gr1,command=amgtires).pack(anchor='w' )
tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text="4",value=4,variable=gr1,command=amgtires).pack(anchor='w' )
tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text="None",value=5,variable=gr1,command=amgtires).pack(anchor='w' )

#Get the total cost for maintenace
amgpage = tk.Button(window10,text= "Get total cost", command = amgtotal,fg = 'Green')
amgpage.pack(anchor='w')



#size for window size
window10.geometry("700x400")

#window title       
window10.title("Mercedes Benz AMG Maintenance Calculator")

#end of window10 loop
window10.mainloop()
```

So when I click I want one tire I just want the 227.92 and 2 tires to get the value for two tires etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of unnecessary block of code. I've corrected few of it, it can get better though.

1. You don't need two `mainloop`, one is just enough to show as many `Toplevel` or `Tk` windows you want. So I removed `window17.mainloop()`.
2. Also use `Toplevel` Window instead of another main window that is `Tk`. There's a reason why `Toplevel exists.`
3. There can be  many approaches to get the values you need, I just used the simplest in which I removed `amgtires()` because it can be done without it.
4. I used `for` loop to create `Radiobutton` makes the job so much easier.

---

**So here is the complete code.**

```
import tkinter as tk
#make a new window
window10 = tk.Tk()
#lable what the page is
amgpage = tk.Label(window10, text="Mercedes Benz AMG Maintenance Calculator")
amgpage.pack(anchor='n')

#ask the user how many tires are needed
amgpage = tk.Label(window10, text="How many new tires do you need?")
amgpage.pack(anchor='w')

gr1=tk.IntVar()
tire_cost = tk.DoubleVar()

def amgtotal():
#open a new page
    window17 = tk.Toplevel()  # Use Toplevel instead of tk.

    #total cost for tires
    amgpage = tk.Label(window17, text="Tire Cost: $"+ str(tire_cost.get()) )
    amgpage.pack(anchor='w')

    #size for window
    window17.geometry("400x400")

    #window title   
    window17.title("Mercedes Benz AMG Maintenance Total")


#radio button on how many tire are needed
for i in range(4):
    tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text=i, variable = gr1, value=i)
    tire['command'] = lambda i=i : tire_cost.set( 227.9*i )
    tire.pack(anchor='w')

tire = tk.Radiobutton(window10, text="None", value=5, variable=gr1)
tire.pack(anchor='w' )

#Get the total cost for maintenace
amgpage = tk.Button(window10,text= "Get total cost", command = amgtotal,fg = 'Green')
amgpage.pack(anchor='w')

#size for window size
window10.geometry("700x400")

#window title       
window10.title("Mercedes Benz AMG Maintenance Calculator")

#end of window10 loop
window10.mainloop()
```

You can make this a lot better, Hope this helps.